# How can I add both image and text into alertbox in android

Tags: android, json, android-alertdialog

I coded like below for creating a alertdialog . alert box works properly but how can I add image into alertbox?? while the title and messages ared parsed strings from my database.I need to add image from database dynamically.

```
  private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
   public void onClick(View v) {
               builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileViewActivity.this).setTitle(ser_name)
                                        .setMessage(desc);
               builder.setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      dialog.cancel();
               }
               }).show();
```

Comment: Create a custom Dialog Layout

Answer (score 0):

Inflate layout to you alertbox

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null);

dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
ImageView imgview = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.img);
imgview.setResource(R.drawable.img);
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

> make you own layout

Comment: not a single image from drawable, i need to add images dynamically from my database

Comment: fetch that image from database.image stored in database in form of bitmap